# sscanf ignores spaces?

Tags: php, string

The following code takes in an `$input` like: `"a banana is a fruit"`

```
$t = sscanf($input,"a %s is a %s",$child,$parent);
echo $t.",".$child.",".$parent;
```

and it outputs: `2,banana,fruit`, which is perfect!

However, if `$input = "a cow is an animal"` we get the output: `2,cow,n`. This is not ideal.

Ideally, for `$input = "a cow is an animal"` it would return `1,cow,` and I will use a separate formatting string:  `"a %s is an %s"` for this input which would return `2,cow,animal`.

So: why doesn't the space after the second `a` in `"a %s is a %s"` stop this problem from occurring? Is there a way to explicitly declare that a space MUST occur after that `a` for it to find a correct match?

Hopefully that makes sense. Any help appreciated!

EDIT: here is the actual code:

```
$teachArray = array("a %s is a %s","an %s is a %s","a %s is an %s","an %s is an %s");
$i=0;
$t = -1;
while( (t <= 2) && (i < count($teachArray)) ) {
    $t = sscanf($input,$teachArray[i],$child,$parent);
    $i++;
}
```

So it keeps looping until it either finds a matching sentence structure, or it runs out of sentence templates (stored in $teachArray).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of scanf, you should use a [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$input = "a cow is an animal";
preg_match("/^an? (.+?) is an? (.+?)$/", $input, $matches);
echo (count($matches)-1) . ',' . $matches[1] . ',' . $matches[2];
```

Comment: Wow. Having witnessed it's power, I'm now going to learn some regular expressions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can still use sscanf for that, even though regexp is more flexible.

```
$t = sscanf($input,"%s %s is %s %s",$a1, $child, $a2, $parent);
echo $t.",".$child.",".$parent;
```